# How to make an upload progress bar with ASP.net C# and ExtJS 4?

Tags: c#, javascript, upload, extjs4, progress-bar

Here is the current code:
JS:

```
var files = new Array();

function () {
                var me = this;

                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var formData = new FormData();

                    formData.append('files', files[i]);
                    formData.append('folderId', (Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#treePanel')[0]).getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].data.id);

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhr.open('post', '/File/Upload', true);
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                            me.getUserSessionStore().load();
                            me.getFilesStore().load();
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.send(formData);
                }
```

}

And C#:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase files, long folderId)
    {
        var user = new UsersModel().GetUserByEmail(User.Identity.Name);

        if (files != null)
        {
            string x = Path.GetExtension(files.FileName);

            if (new FilesModel().GetFileTypes().ToList().Where(a => a.ftp_extension == x.TrimStart('.')).Count() != 0)
            {
                var dbPath = new FilesModel().GetPaths().First();
                var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files.FileName);
                var fileType = new FilesModel().GetFileTypes().ToList().First(a => a.ftp_extension == x.TrimStart('.'));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("/Temp/") + user.usr_id);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Temp/") + user.usr_id + "/", fileName);
                files.SaveAs(path);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dbPath.pth_path + "/tmp/" + user.usr_id + "/");
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/Temp/" + user.usr_id + "/" + fileName)))
                    System.IO.File.Move(Server.MapPath("/Temp/" + user.usr_id + "/" + fileName), dbPath.pth_path + "tmp/" + user.usr_id + "/" + fileName);

                var fileId = new FilesModel().CreateFile(user.usr_id, fileName, false, "", fileName, 1, fileType.ftp_id, user.usr_id, folderId);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(dbPath.pth_path + "tmp/" + user.usr_id + "/" + fileName))
                    System.IO.File.Move(dbPath.pth_path + "tmp/" + user.usr_id + "/" + fileName, dbPath.pth_path + new Pass().getMd5Hash(fileId.ToString()));
                return Content("{success:true, result:\"File uploaded correctly\"}");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("{success:false, error:\"Unsupported file type\"}");
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            ContentType = "text/html",
            Data = new { success = false, error = "File uploaded error" }
        };
    }
}
```

How can I make a progress bar that reprents the upload progression in the server side ? How do I get the upload progression of the `SaveAs` (if it's possible), and if it's not what do I have to change ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There are a couple of samples over here on SO.. Where did you get the code you posted?

Comment: This is my code. And yes I've read some thread, but didn't find answers for my problem.

Comment: What you have to change? A LOT! I'v seen a lot of controller-actions to upload a file but his one...

Comment: What is you problem precise? Having a progressbar is nice, but what do you want to solve, so seem to upload 1 file at a time. If you have the idea that most of the time will be spend in .SaveAs() your mistaken. How much time it takes to save an file of 1Mb to disk? millisecs. Most of your time is spend on the wire; from client to server.

Comment: The upload method work, the only thing that I want to fix is the upload progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it clientside as your are iterating through your filelist there. Updating the progressbar clientside from script should be trivial.

Updating your progressbar from activity on the server requires callbacks from server to client (for which you can use SignalR) or polling from the client. Both options require a substantial amount of work to get right.

I get the feeling that you are not an experienced programmer, so unless this is your own pet-project I would go for the first option.